# populate array with data from local database

Tags: c#, arrays, database, local, populate

How to populate a Array with a string database row? I´m using local database "Service-based database" that visual studio 15 provide, but I don´t know how to get these data and put to a variable (array).
This database have like 15 rows. I want to check if the user input on textBox match one of this 15 rows.

Comment: A datatable is already a handy container: a collection of rows each of which contains a collection if fields.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Stil dont get it. Im using `dataset.Table.Rows[0]["field"].ToString()` and geting nothing. By the way, tour done, sry about that, new to the forum.

Comment: I think i get it. Tnk you for the help, dude.

Answer (score 0):

How about you make a List of all the data in your DB and use something like:

```
if(myList.Contains(UserInput))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Match!");
}
```

Unless I don't understand the question correctly. Can you upload a snapshot of your code?

Comment: Tnk you, going to try this.